# flacards.cls and loop don't work together

Tags: packages

I try to automatise the construction of my flashcards.
I try with `\foreach` (tikz) and `\forloop` (forloop package), it's not working.
The error is in the two case:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

The code :

```
\documentclass{flacards}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{forloop} 

\begin{document}
\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 11}{ 
  \card{\arabic{ct}}{}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify some text also in the second argument. (La)TeX needs to go into *horizontal mode*, otherwise the error will show.

Since `\null` doesn't activate horizontal mode, it's useless. So

```
\card{\arabic{ct}}{~}
```

or `\card{\arabic{ct}}{\ }` will work.

Comment: Ha, now that is obvious now!  And probably the cleanest way is to use `\leavevmode` in the second argument.

Comment: I understand my error.I tried to do short loop test just to see the result whitout the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what's going on in the `\card` macro (and unfortunately I don't have time to investigate it), but it seems that the empty second argument is the culprit.  Interestingly enough, `\card{\arabic{ct}}{\null}` does not help (anyone has any idea why?), but `\card{\arabic{ct}}{\ }` does.

(And obviously the loop has nothing to do with that.)